# CloudKit - CKFetchRecordsOperation no response

Tags: swift, cloudkit

When using a `CKFetchRecordsOperation` I am not getting a response.

This is in Xcode Version 7.0 beta 4 (7A165t).

```
import Cocoa
import CloudKit

// A record exists in the public container with this ID.
let recordIDs = [CKRecordID(recordName: "E175411C-58C9-4CF6-89AE-23E53289EE46")];

let fetchRecords = CKFetchRecordsOperation(recordIDs: recordIDs);

fetchRecords.fetchRecordsCompletionBlock = { (records:[CKRecordID: CKRecord]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
    // Code never reached
    debugPrint("fetchRecordsCompletionBlock")
}

fetchRecords.perRecordCompletionBlock = { (record, recordID, error) -> Void in
    // Code never reached.
    debugPrint("perRecordCompletionBlock")
}
fetchRecords.perRecordProgressBlock = { (recordID, progress) -> Void in
    // Code never reached.
    debugPrint("perRecordProgressBlock")
}

fetchRecords.completionBlock = {
    // Code never reached.
    debugPrint("completionBlock")
}

let database = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase

fetchRecords.database = database
fetchRecords.start()
```

I have tried both methods to add the operation to the queue:

```
let database = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
fetchRecords.database = database
fetchRecords.start()
```

and

```
let database = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
database.addOperation(fetchRecords)
```

I get no activity in the console, and the handlers are never reached.

If I query the record like this, I successfully get the result.

```
database.fetchRecordWithID(recordID) { (record:CKRecord?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            debugPrint("Result"); // The record here exists, and is as expected.

        }
```

However, I have an array of `CKRecordID` - hence why I need `CKFetchRecordsOperation` to work.

Comment: You definitely do not want to call `start` on the operation. You must use `addOperation` to start the operation.

Comment: When you call `fetchRecordWithID`, do you get the expected record or an error? Simply printing "Result" doesn't mean it worked.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the correct record. The record exists and fetchRecordWithID returns it.

I have also tried `addOperation` - the outcome is the same (although Apple do suggest using the `start` approach: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/AddingReferences/AddingReferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH12-SW2

Comment: I have added a report on Apple Bug Reporter with case ID 22106406

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in Xcode 7 beta 4.

In Xcode Version 7.0 beta 5 (7A176x) it works as expected.